# Reading all available messages from mpsc UnboundedReceiver without blocking unnecessarily

Tags: concurrency, rust, future

I have an `futures::sync::mpsc::unbounded` channel.  I can send messages  to the `UnboundedSender<T>` but have problems receiving them from the `UnboundedReciever<T>`.
I use the channel to send messages to the UI thread, and I have a function that gets called every frame, and I'd like to read all the available messages from the channel on each frame, without blocking the thread when there are no available messages.

From what I've read the `Future::poll` method is kind of what I need, I just poll, and if I get Async::Ready, I do something with the message, and if not, I just return from the function.
The problem is the `poll` panics when there is no task context (I'm not sure what that means or what to do about it).

What I tried:

```
let (sender, receiver) = unbounded(); // somewhere in the code, doesn't matter
// ...
let fut = match receiver.by_ref().collect().poll() {
    Async::Ready(items_vec) => // do something on UI with items,
    _ => return None
}
```

this panics because I don't have a task context.

Also tried:

```
let (sender, receiver) = unbounded(); // somewhere in the code, doesn't matter
// ...
let fut = receiver.by_ref().collect(); // how do I run the future?
tokio::runtime::current_thread::Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(fut); // this blocks the thread when there are no items in the receiver
```

I would like help with reading the `UnboundedReceiver<T>` without blocking the thread when there are no items in the stream (just do nothing then).

Thanks!

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming Added examples of what I tried

Answer (score 0):

You are using futures incorrectly -- you need a `Runtime` and a bit more boilerplate to get this to work:

```rust
    extern crate tokio;
    extern crate futures;
    
    use tokio::prelude::*;
    use futures::future::{lazy, ok};
    use futures::sync::mpsc::unbounded;
    use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
    
    fn main() {
        let (sender, receiver) = unbounded::<i64>();
        let receiver = receiver.for_each(|result| {
            println!("Got: {}", result);
            Ok(())
        });
    
        let rt = Runtime::new().unwrap();
        rt.executor().spawn(receiver);
    
        let lazy_future = lazy(move || {
            sender.unbounded_send(1).unwrap();
            sender.unbounded_send(2).unwrap();
            sender.unbounded_send(3).unwrap();
            ok::<(), ()>(())
        });
    
        rt.block_on_all(lazy_future).unwrap();
    }
```

Further reading, from [Tokio's runtime model](https://tokio.rs/docs/internals/runtime-model/):

> [...]in order to use Tokio and successfully execute tasks, an application must start an executor and the necessary drivers for the resources that the application’s tasks depend on. This requires significant boilerplate. To manage the boilerplate, Tokio offers a couple of runtime options. A runtime is an executor bundled with all necessary drivers to power Tokio’s resources. Instead of managing all the various Tokio components individually, a runtime is created and started in a single call.
>
> Tokio offers a [concurrent runtime](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.8/tokio/runtime/index.html) and a [single-threaded runtime](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.8/tokio/runtime/current_thread/index.html). The concurrent runtime is backed by a multi-threaded, work-stealing executor. The single-threaded runtime executes all tasks and drivers on thee current thread. The user may pick the runtime with characteristics best suited for the application.